# Ошибка компиляции CMake Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Я собираю проект на Ubuntu, и у меня возникла проблема при обращении к библиотеке epoxylib.

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/DEngine.dir/main.cpp.o: неопределённая ссылка
>   на символ «epoxy_glVertex3fv» /usr/bin/ld:
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0: ошибка добавления символов: в
>   командной строке не указан DSO collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DEngine.dir/build.make:165: DEngine]
>   Ошибка 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76:
>   CMakeFiles/DEngine.dir/all] Ошибка 2 make: *** [Makefile:84: all]
>   Ошибка 2

Мой CMake.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(GLProject VERSION 0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -pthread -lGL -lglut")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(GLProject ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_libraries(GLProject ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

Код взял от сюда: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/cube.c

Comment: Судя по всему не линкуется какая-то из трех библиотек. Проверьте что содержат переменные `${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY}`  message(STATUS  ${GTK3_LIBRARIES}).

Comment: Проверил линковку библиотек, все три библиотеки линкуются

Comment: Судя по названию функции, эта функция из opengl. Убедитесь что путь содержащийся в ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} существует на вашей машине. Если существует, значит этой функции нет в вашей версии библиотеки.